# Getting the scale, placement and color correct

Tags: simulation

I am trying to create a graphic with the sun, moon, and earth in the same frame as if looking from the end of the Apex node, assuming a 100,000 km tether, but with the correct sizes, placement, axis angle and color.  Something like this.....
[image]

This graphic has issues....
1) It is not from the point of view of the Apex node at 100,000.
2) I have no idea if there is ever a time in the orbits of the earth, moon and sun where they would close enough to preserve the scale.
3) I have no idea if the colors are correct.
4) In the real world the tether would loose visibility quickly as it get farther away from the view point.  But how soon? 100km out?
5) It is not to scale.

Question 1) Where would a non-expert go to get answers?
Question 2) Is there software that can do this?

Comment: Can you explain a little more what the "tether" is? Does it need to be in the picture?  As for software, I would suggest Celestia ( http://www.shatters.net/celestia/ ) might help, it's a free download and will allow you to try view points.

Comment: A professional author explains best   http://www.space.com/24739-space-elevator-tether-technology.html

Comment: The site at the link is not working yet....."shatters.net
is a totally awesome idea still being worked on.

Check back later."

Comment: Celestia itself is a download (from that page) that runs under Windows. If you do a general web search for "Celestia space elevator" you will find a people have already produced models and images of this popular subject. Well worth a look...

Comment: It seems the h t t p : / / w w w ." prefix, without the spaces in between, is required .http://www.shatters.net/celestia/

Comment: @Andy the download page shows three different OS - is Windows preferred?

Comment: For getting the best shot from a "planetarium" software (like Celestia) look around equinox time (near end of March and end of September), when the Sun lines up with Earth's equator (where the tether would need to be anchored). Moon's orbital period is not synchronous with Earth's orbital period in any apparent way, so check various years until you find its ascending node near the Earth-Sun line during an equinox, and you'll be able to line it up really close as well. Then use the Field of View (FOV) setting to get a neat close-up.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I would like to thanks Andy for giving me the link to the [Celestia software](http://www.shatters.net/celestia/) that got me the answer.